# React-Native What is the timeout and maximumAge in geolocation

Tags: geolocation, react-native, react-native-ios

I am currently learning react-native and I am working on a an application that uses Geolocation to find and update my current location and I am following a tutorial for that and in the tutorial I had to use a property with the **timeout** and **maximumAge** options.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pozitie)=>{
        var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
        var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)

        // create an object with the current position taken from the geolocation chip
        var initialLocation = {
          latitude = lat,
          longitude = long,

          // Delta is the viewing angle on the location of the user
          latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
          longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
        }
        // Now we are seting initial position to the initial location 
        this.setState({initialPositionOnTheMap: initialLocation})

        // we set the marker to the initial location and then the display follows the marker
        // by using the initialLocaiton object that will receive the users current location
        this.setState({positionOfTheMarker: initialLocation})
      }, 

      // make a function call if an error happens
      // we make an allert that parses the error message
      (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
      // propertie
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 2000, maximumAge: 1000})
```

but it didn't explain what does **timeout** and **maximumAge** mean, why do we use them.

I know that these options are used in two methods provided by react-native:   getCurrentPosition(Invokes a callback with the latest location) and watchPosition(Invokes a callback whenever the location has changed) but I don't understand what are they doing exactly.

Comment: Here is the best description I've found so far [from Mozilla website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions)

Answer (score 5):

I have asked the creator of the tutorial, and he responded:

**Timeout**: is a positive value that indicates the maximum time the device is allowed to return a position.

**MaximumAge**: is a positive value indicating the maximum age in milliseconds of a possible cached position that is acceptable to return. In other words, how old can cached locations be before I should start getting the current location to return.﻿

Comment: android does not provide location update while app is in foreground, iOS does perfectly.

Comment: What happens if the timeout is longer than the age? (and it takes the majority of the timeout time to return the value)